# plotting a 3d chart for a range of values

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a range of x, y and z values.I want to visualise this as a 3d or surface plot/chart. I know how to visualise if I have a function or discrete data. For example if I have, x is from 20 to 50 and y is from -3 to 10 and z is from -2 to 10. There is no individual values want to visualise the entire range using max and min values, how I can plot this? 
Ps: three axes are respectively l*a*b color space

Comment: Do you have your data on a structured grid?

Comment: Thanks. I dont have individual data but only ranges with minimum and maximum number

Comment: Isn't it better to show us the x,y and z by writing their code? I presume that you have three maximum and minimum values by which I do not know how you want the surface look like!!

Comment: In 2d if I have min and max value, don't we get a shaded/enclosed area? Why not then a curved surface in 3d?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have your data on uniform structured grid, and your Z-values are represented by a matrix. Then,

```
nx = 33;
ny = 33;
xlin = linspace(min(x),max(x),nx);
ylin = linspace(min(y),max(y),ny);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(xlin,ylin);

surf(X,Y,Z)
```

`Z` is a `ny` by `nx` matrix holding the z-values of your data.